# Fast targz unArchiver

Tags: java, gzip, tar

following Question:

I have a tarGz archive, that is filled with about 1 000 000 protoBuffer files, which I have to unpack and process.
At the moment the fastes way I found is by untaring it with the [TarArchiveInputStream](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/tar/TarArchiveInputStream.html) from apache.commons.
The untaring part is my bottleneck at the moment, cause it takes about 20mins to unpack it.

Can this be done any faster?
Is their a way to untar a targz File with multiple threads, I accually have no idea if this can work?

Any help is appreciated.

My untar function:

```
public void untar(String tarPath) throws IOException {
        try(TarArchiveInputStream fin = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(new FileInputStream(tarPath)))){
            UnzipperThreadHandler.setFinished(false);

            TarArchiveEntry entry;
            File out = new File((new File(tarPath).getParent())+"/help");

            while ((entry = fin.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                File curfile = new File(out, entry.getName());
                File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
                if (!parent.exists()) {
                    parent.mkdirs();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(curfile);
                IOUtils.copy(fin, fos);
                fos.close();
            }

            UnzipperThreadHandler.setFinished(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with the TarArchiveInputStream but rather with the FileOutputStream which is completely unbuffered.You should wrap this with a BufferedOutputStream.

Additionally the IOUtils.copyLarge method allows you to specify a buffer size. Depending on the file size you may profit from reading larger chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your help but still not the improvement i was hoping for. 
I also removed the parent.exists() like @Joop Eggen suggested, cause this could be a performance issue. But still same outcome.